# What type of class to use for parameter to IObjectExplorerService.ConnectToServer() in regards to SSMS extension

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In regards to [IObjectExplorerService.ConnectToServer()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.ui.vsintegration.objectexplorer.iobjectexplorerservice.connecttoserver?view=sqlserver-2016) I wonder what kind of class to pass as connectionInfo.

This is an extension for SQL Server Management Studio.

Here's the signature for the method:

```
void ConnectToServer(System::Object ^ connectionInfo);
```

And if you know the answer, please also tell for future reference how I can figure out what it expects.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to decompile Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.dll and find the method.

Ended up with this for Windows Authentication:

```
UIConnectionInfo connInfo = new UIConnectionInfo
{
    ServerName = @"servername\instance",
    ServerType = SqlServerType.ServerType,
    AuthenticationType = 3,
    OtherParams = "TrustServerCertificate=True"
};

service.ConnectToServer(connInfo);
```